# Math.Round with dependency properties, wierd behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a dependency property 'Area' as :

```
public double Area
    {
        get { return Math.Round((double)this.GetValue(AreaProperty),2); } 
        set { this.SetValue(AreaProperty, value); }
    }
```

I am adding some visuals using code and updating the area as the visuals are added. 
I wanted the value to be roundoff to two decimal places.

```
drawQuads(builder);  //Updating area in these three methods
extrudeQuads();
drawSidesAndBottoms(builder);

Area *= 1;  //this is required so that the roundoff method can work (Why ?)
```

As you can see getter of the property is rounding off the value. But the problem is rounding does not work unless I multiply the 'Area' by 1 or something else after calling these three methods.

Please explain whats the reason, Why do I need to multiply it by 1?

**EDIT :**

Actually those methods are updating  Area using the statement like :

```
Area += someFormula;
```

Isn't it calling the getter? and even if it is not, finally I am displaying the value in a label (actually binded this property to the label Content property so as the Area changes Label.Content also updates).

Comment: Can you confirm that the value of `Area` is changing to the correct value (although not rounded) and the get/set methods are always being called?

Comment: Actually, what you probably want is one property that stores the value with full precision and another read-only property that does the rounding for binding purposes. You could also use a binding converter to do the rounding.

Comment: @keyboardP yes, it seems so (i am not sure, just learning), please have look at the edit.

Comment: @default.kramer Yes, that can work but I didn't want to create a whole converter for just rounding off values. And I don't want to store with the full precision. I tried putting Math.Round in the setter and it worked but still don't know the reason why it didn't work when Math.Round was in the getter. Please suggest something as I am just learning.

Comment: Where you have `public double Area` - that is just a "convenience wrapper" for `this.GetValue(AreaProperty)` and the binding system does not call the "convenience wrapper". So the rounding code only gets hit when you access the wrapper. If you must encode the rounding into the property, you probably need a `CoerceValueCallback` but I would recommend using a separate property instead.

Comment: See the big warning on [page 53 of WPF Unleashed](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780672328916/samplechapter/0672328917_CH03.pdf)

Comment: Looks like that's the answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: @default.kramer OK, i know now that why Math.Round didn't work in getter. But why did it work when I did Area *= 1; ? (Is that a stupid question ? ) Sorry for disturbing you again.

Comment: Because `Area *= 1` is equivalent to `Area = Area * 1` which does call the getter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When WPF's dependency property system gets your `Area` property, it doesn't really call `get_Area` (i.e. the `get` you declared there).  Instead, it gets the value behind-the-scenes through what you can think of as `this.GetValue(AreaProperty)`.  `Area *= 1` (or similar, e.g. `Area = Area`) causes your getter to actually be called, and the rounded value to then be set to the real backing value.

I'm not sure if the same thing happens with your setter, so you might want to try putting your rounding in there instead to see if anything changes:

```
public double Area
{
    get { return (double)this.GetValue(AreaProperty); } 
    set { this.SetValue(AreaProperty, Math.Round(value,2)); }
}
```

If this doesn't work, I'd try one of two things: (1) rethink your whole approach and come at this from a different angle - e.g. if you just need it rounded when displayed as a string, use a string format to do so, or (2) create a `RoundedDouble` class that implicitly converts to and from `double`, but with your rounding in place, and use that for `Area`.